# How to generate MPEG-DASH stream with ClearKey DRM using FFmpeg

Tags: encryption, ffmpeg, drm

I want to create an MPEG-DASH stream with ClearKey DRM using FFmpeg.

The stream generation is already complete and working (using the C API)

How could I (using either C or the CLI) add ClearKey DRM to the stream?

Happy to hear answers for both VOD and live as a pointer to get started

Comment: Do you mean a live stream or a VOD stream (created from an mp4 file for example) - its likely worth specifying to make sure you get the answer you need?

Comment: Shouldn't make a difference regarding this should it? Only difference would be how you supply the data to FFmpeg and what you do for your IO

Comment: Well it's usually a bit different - you may find that often tools and command to work on files are different  than on streams. For example you can generate DASH content from an MP4 file using a particular mp4Box command.

Comment: Ultimately I won't be using any commands as this is part of a larger system integration but in that point I would be happy for any pointers, live or VOD, as that will point me in the right direction (and show if it's even possible from FFmpeg)

Comment: It may be possible with FFMPEG, hopefully someone confirm one way or the other - you can certainly create DASH streams and manifest unencrypted, as I am guessing you probably know already, Most often I have seen MP4Box used however to package mp4 into encrypted DASH. Not sure if this a possibility for you: https://github.com/gpac/gpac/wiki/MP4Box